# Error en dataframe. arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0. GoogleSearchConsoleR

Tags: r, rstudio, google-search-console

Pido información a la API de GoogleSearchConsole a través del la librería de MarkEdmonson
(https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/searchConsoleR), hago login en una cuenta de google, limpio los data frames para volcar la información requerida,  pido la información de una serie de urls en un documento de GoogleSheets. Y creo un bucle for para obtener estos insights. Pero con uno de los insight obtenidos me encuentro con el problema de "arguments imply diffeering number of rows" y me falla, adjunto imagen: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pongo el trozo de código con una solución temporal que hace mostrar "-" al detectar que es una lista:

```
scr_auth( email = "")

#  Preparacion urls y de Data.frames previos al bucle
#urls_input -> lista de urls a indexar dentro de google_Drive
list_url <- read_sheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/')

#df.data = data.frame()
#df.data_historic = data.frame()

df.data = readRDS("draft_data")
df.data = df.data[0,]
df.data = saveRDS(df.data,"draft_data")

df.data_historic = readRDS("draft_historic")
df.data_historic = df.data_historic[0,]
df.data_historic = saveRDS(df.data_historic, "draft_historic")

#  Bucle for para indexacion de list_url
for (x in 1:nrow(list_url)) {
  
  api_response= inspection( inspectionUrl = list_url$url[x],#df.DRAFT$nombre_column[x]
                            siteUrl = "https://www..com/", 
                            languageCode = "es"
  )
  
  #creacion de las variables para el data.frame
  urls = as.character(list_url$url[x])
lastCrawlTime = ifelse(is_list(api_response$indexStatusResult$lastCrawlTime),"-",api_response$indexStatusResult$lastCrawlTime)

  #creacion del dataframe #df.results_daily
  df.data = data.frame(
    "Urls" = list_url$url[x],
    "LastCrawlTime" = lastCrawlTime
    
  )
  #Plasmar datos df.results_daily en results_historic
  df.data_historic = rbind(df.data,df.data_historic)
  saveRDS(df.data_historic,"draft_historic")
  print(x)
  Sys.sleep(5) 
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido alehandro a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Si el el error se corresponde con el código, te puedo sugerir que revises `lastCrawlTime` por que pareciera estar vacio en el momento en que creas el data.frame.

Comment: He añadido una foto del resultado de `lastCrawlTime`  cuando me da el fallo (Error in data.frame(Urls = list_url$url[x], LastCrawlTime = lastCrawlTime) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0), genera una list(), pero cuando obtiene el dato de la fecha continua el código. ¿Sabrías decirme que puedo hacer en este caso? Dado que con la solución que yo realizo arriba siempre muestra "-" @PatricioMoracho Gracias

Comment: En primer lugar, no sabemos en que línea exacta está dando el error, yo estoy suponiendo que es aquí: `df.data = data.frame("Urls" = list_url$url[x],"LastCrawlTime" = lastCrawlTime )` pero deberías confirmarlo. Si es ahí el error, pareciera que el problema es que `LastCrawlTime` está vacía, algo como ejecutar esto: `data.frame("Urls" = "una url",   "LastCrawlTime" = list())`. Mucho más no podemos decir, el único que puede hacer debug eres tú, a menos que agregues un [mcve]. Saludos.